# multiple commands grep

Tags: linux, x86, grep

I want to search through file gdb.txt for the following assembly expression:

```
    call DWORD PTR [EDI]
```

but doing

```
   grep -e "call DWORD PTR [EDI]" -f gdb.txt
```

doesn't return anything. Ideas?

Comment: maybe: `call DWORD PTR [EDI] |  grep -e -f gdb.txt` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the open-bracket, which is a special regular expression character.  Also, the -f option doesn't do what you think it does.  You just need to specify your file after the pattern.  Also, you don't even really need the -e.  So it comes down to this:

```
grep "call DWORD PTR \[EDI]" gdb.txt
```